# Can't link to static library in Xcode workspace

Tags: objective-c, static-linking

I have an Xcode workspace containing two projects, JDPlayer and JDComposer. JDComposer compiles to a static library, which JDPlayer needs to link to.

JDComposer builds fine, and libJDComposer shows up in the build products directory. JDPlayer then compiles fine, too - but when it comes to trying to link to libJDComposer.a, there are a bunch of problems, all along these lines:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"JDComposer::getSyncTypes(std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >&)", referenced from:
  JDPlayer::getSyncTypes(std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >&) in JDPlayer.o
```

I have added libJDComposer.a to JDPlayer->Target->Build Phases->Link Binary With Libraries. I have also added the path of libJDComposer.a to JDPlayer->Build Settings->Library Search Paths.

It's worth noting that libJDComposer.a has 2 targets - libJDComposeriOS and libJDComposerOSX. I am trying to link to libJDComposerOSX, since JDPlayer is an OSX project.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: Obviously JDComposer::getSyncTypes cannot be found in your linked archive. Are you sure that symbol is defined in JDComposer? You could for example use nm to find out. You might also want to make sure you are linking with an archive built for x86_64 and not any other arch (lipo -info will tell available archs).

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Unfortunately, that symbol is definitely defined in JDComposer, and the archive is built for x86_64. Any other ideas?

Comment: There are no comments about library being ignored in your build logs? You can typically see those if the linker picks a library built for some other architecture. If the library is build for the right arch and you are sure it defines those missing symbols there must be something wrong with the linking. You should be able to see the command line of the link step somewhere. Make sure Xcode does what you expect.